# state with different name but same array changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I define 2 states with the same array, it's `listRasioUom` and `showListRasioUom`. but when I `setstate` to `listRasioUom` state, the `showListRasioUom` state also changed with the same value as `listRasioUom`. any help? this is my code

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    if (["rasio", "uom"].includes(e.target.name)) {
      let listRasioUom = this.state.listRasioUom
      if(listRasioUom.some(el => el.uom === e.target.value))
      {
        alert('Duplicate uom')
      }
      else

        listRasioUom[e.target.dataset.id][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ listRasioUom })
      }
    } 
  }
```

showListRasioUom state is used for fetching the data on my datatables, while listRasioUom state is used to modified the state, so i only want to change listrasiouom state, but when i use setstate on listRasioUom state, the showListRasioUom also change.

```
<MDBDataTable
          info={false}
          paging={false}
          searching={false}
          striped
          bordered
          small
          data={{columns: this.state.columns, rows: this.state.showListRasioUom}}
          noBottomColumns
 />
```

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: The above code doesn't show any usage of `showListRasioUom`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri showListRasioUom is used for fetching the data to the tables row, listRasioUom used to change the list

Comment: You should give us more information about your code.

Comment: updated @s.hesam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object and arrayss in javascript are assigned by reference and if you mutate the original array the other array which also holds the same reference is also updated

You should update your data in an immutable manner

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    if (["rasio", "uom"].includes(e.target.name)) {
      let listRasioUom = this.state.listRasioUom
      if(listRasioUom.some(el => el.uom === e.target.value))
      {
        alert('Duplicate uom')
      }
      else {
        const id = e.target.dataset.id;
        const {name,value} = e.target;
        this.setState(prev => ({ 
            listRasioUom: prev.listRasioUom.map((item, i) => {
                if(i == id) return {...item, [name]: value};
             })
             return item;
         }))
      }
    } 
  }
```